# Problem with processing count column with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to process the count column in my action how to do with help of hiberante.in my application every class is mapped to every table  here I'm using billing table. In billing table details and other columns are there.
If i pass the query into execute sql query method it  getting all the details, but it  returns the count column as that corresponding dao class. How to process that column. Here is my query.

```
select u,b,b,count(b.details) from com.cod.model.Billing b,com.cod.model.User u where b.accountId=u.id and b.details not like '%Monthly Package With Usage Value Rs:0.0%' and b.details not like '%A/C Opened:%' and b.details not like '%Voucher Recharged%' and b.details not like '%default0%' group by u.username,b.details
```

Here it's getting user and billing table values but count column also comes as billing table object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the results list type safe or hibernate will grab everything he can and push it in an instance of that object. When you make your results list not type safe hibernate will just return an List over which you can iterate and retrieve the fields you need.

List.get(0)[3] should result in you having your count.

String hql = "...";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
//List< com.cod.model.Billing> results = query.list();
List results = query.list();